# Python best way to 'flip' a string of parentheses

Tags: python

I want to write a program that "reflects" a string of parentheses across the y axis. So for example,  `((()(` would become `)()))`. I know that it can be done like this:

```
s = '((()('
par = '(', ')'
result = ''.join([par[1 - par.index(p)] for p in s[::-1]])
```

Is there a more concise / more pythonic way to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd combine slicing with `str.translate()`:

```
In [16]: s = '((()('

In [17]: tr = str.maketrans('()', ')(')

In [18]: s[::-1].translate(tr)
Out[18]: ')()))'
```

Comment: @TerryA `s[::-1].translate(tr)` then

Comment: Then I don't understand the OP's requirements. Deleting.

Comment: All that was needed was a reversal of the input string, *and* the translation: `s[::-1].translate(tr)`. This is the better approach over using a dict.

Answer (score 2):

```
''.join({'(':')', ')':'('}[c] for c in s[::-1])
```

Comment: It's the same approach as OP's, but that just goes to show that there's no need to make something more optimal. Good answer

Comment: `str.translate()` would be a lot more efficient.

Comment: I don't like building the dictionary for every character.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
d = {'(':')', ')':'('}
s = '((()('
new_d = ''.join(d[i] for i in s[::-1])
```

Output:

```
')()))'
```

Edit: without dictionary:

```
new_s = ''.join(chr(ord(i)-1) if ord(i)%40 else chr(ord(i)+1) for i in s[::-1])
```

Output:

```
')()))'
```

Comment: Surely `')' if i == '(' else '('` would be better in pretty much every way?

Answer (score 0):

```
p = {'(': ')', ')': '('}
s = '((()('
s = ''.join(p[e] for e in s[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ref = lambda s:''.join( chr(ord(e)^1) for e in s[::-1])
print(ref('((()('))     # )()))
```

Basically the idea is converting `)` to `(` by flipping the last bit of its ascii value.

`)`'s ascii is 41

41^1 --> 40 --> ascii of `(`.

And vice versa for `(`.